# Is sftp always possible when there is ssh available?

Tags: ssh, sftp

Is secure FTP (sftp) using SSH (port number 22) always possible when there is ssh available? Currently I'm using PuTTY for SSH. I want to upload files using CuteFTP Pro.

Or do I need ftp server on the server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, on the server side you need an sftp-binary as well. OpenSSH ships one they call sftp-server. Usually resides in /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server (on a Debian machine for example)

CuteFTP has support for sftp. But keep in mind that your server needs sftp-server on that end first.

Answer (score 1):

For sshd (OpenSSH SSH daemon), its a configuration option, which by default is switched on. Look out for the line

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. To disable just remove that line.

Comment: It's not a configuration option. You can't assume that if you have an SSH server you automagically have an sftp server waiting to be "switched on". You also need the sftp-server binary.

Comment: Hmm. But this server is usually installed when the sshd-package is installed. But in a pure view, yes, you are right, you need that binary. No beer, no drinking beer.

Comment: @Amestig, the SFTP server could be built into the SSH server. An external program is not really required. For instance, latest versions of OpenSSH server can be configured to use an external SFTP server or the built-in one.

Comment: @salva, i just checked the latest OpenSSH makefile and no changes are made there that "includes" the sftp-server inside the sshd binary. It's still a single target in the makefile and you can't assume that just because you have sshd on a system you automatically have sftp-server. Of course, a lot of distributions ship all OpenSSH binaries in their packages when installing sshd, but you can't assume it's there.

Comment: @Arnestig, check again, it has been there since [OpenSSH 4.9](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-4.9)!

Comment: I stand corrected. Changelog from OpenSSH 4.9 states: Linked sftp-server(8) into sshd(8). The internal sftp server is
    used when the command "internal-sftp" is specified in a Subsystem
    or ForceCommand declaration. When used with ChrootDirectory, the
    internal sftp server requires no special configuration of files
    inside the chroot environment. Please refer to sshd_config(5) for
    more information.